# cordova geolocation background android

Tags: geolocation, push-notification, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

We have a location based cross platform app built using Ionic. We had built the ability to receive notifications based on the user location using the christocracy plugin   at : https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.

Unfortunately, this works only when the app is open. Besides, there is a display in the android drawer that background location is on. We have tried a variety of sources including the geo-location plugin and the suggestions at http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/.

We are unable to find an option where we can obtain user location even after the app is closed and serve notifications based on the users location. We have tried practically any solution and plugin we can lay our hands on. We have also looked at every question related this but are unable to find a solution. Are we approaching this wrong? Please help. It is a cross platform app developed using Ionic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no any plugin available that get and give location in background service.

You need to develop native android plugin which get location data in background mode and use native android plugin in ionic project otherwise no any readymade option avaliable.

Comment: Is this something you have done and have implemented elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a plugin.  Have a look at this:

https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-keep-it-running-in-background-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugins/

There are a number of issues with Android 10 though.
This app does work in Android 10 as it is...

Comment: Also, more specifically for Background Location:

Comment: https://blog.appit-online.de/background-geolocation-tracking-with-ionic-4/